# Why does the Runtime error occur?

Tags: c

I am coding in Code-Blocks Editor with GNU GCC Compiler.I wrote the following code(including the relevant libraries and Header files)

```
int main()
{
char a;
scanf("%c",&a);
switch(a)
{
 case '1':
 scanf("%c",&a);
   if(a=='3')
    {
    printf("3\n");
    }else
    {
    printf("4\n");
    }


 break;

 case '2':
 printf("HELLO\n");
 break;

}



return 0;
}
```

When I ran the code,the terminal showed the cursor in order to get the character.I typed `1` and pressed return key.So it wanted me to enter another character.This time i typed `3` and pressed the return key again.Instead of printing `3` at the terminal something bad happened:a runtime error.
Why did that happen?Which bad mistake did i made?Did i ignore some Scope Rules?if i did,which scope Rule did i ignore?

Comment: What does the whole error say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the program. You only need to skip the `'\n'` character left behind by the previous `scanf`.
When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then an extra character `'\n'` goes to the input buffer. This `'\n'` is left behind by the current `scanf`. On next read `scanf` will read this leftover character and you will get unexpected behavior of the program.

To skip this newline character you can place a space before `%c`

```
scanf(" %c",&a);  
  //   ^^ A space before %c can eat up any number of white spaces.
```

[Another way](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) is to put this line after each `scanf`

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

Comment: whats the difference between them?can you explain more?

Comment: @Agent47; What do you mean by *"them"*?

Comment: @ConradMeyer; No. Its `ch != '\n'`. Read characters until either `EOF`  or `'\n'` comes. When any of them will come then the condition `!=` will become `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `scanf("%c",&a);` to `scanf(" %c",&a);` That's basic rule to skip space from input buffer when reading character from stdin.